# Find my mobile but on a different or second mobile

Tags: geolocation, location-services, profiles

I have login or setup with my Google credentials into a different mobile. So now my profile is active in 2 different mobiles.

When I use [Find My Device](https://www.google.com/android/find?u=0), only the second mobile sounds. Is there any way to select which one to find or how to select the desired mobile to find?

Answer (score 1):

At the top left there are icons for each device, and you can tap on one to select a different device.

This may include older devices if you haven't removed them from your account yet, but they'll fail to work if you're not signed into the device.

For example I have a tablet listed that I no longer own and removed my account from and it eventually fails to connect with the message "Can't reach device".

Best to let the sound play for a moment before pressing the power button as it may not be detected on first press otherwise.

Note that this is a website-layout-dependent answer and the moment they change it this will be invalidated.